# VB run time error 6 overlow

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

I am facing VB run time 6 overflow.
When the time I fetch the result from database and put inside variable,
I got this error, overflow.

I understood I can change to `dim a as long`, and this problems will be solve.
but is it every variable I need to declare as long, so I wouldn't face this problem?

This problems doesn't exist until my database row id is larger than 30,000++.

Is there anyway I can prevent this issues?

Comment: You can't have been programming in VB6 for too long.  Don't waste your time and your mind on it, move to VB.NET.  The Express edition is a free download.

Comment: VB.Net would not face this issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, in vb6 an integer data type is limited to 32K or so.  So if you start having variables kick over that, you will start getting overflow errors.

(And here's an [MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199809) on numeric types in VB)

Comment: +1 I don't know why you're concerned about declaring every variable as a `Long`. There's nothing magical about an `Integer`. If you need to (or might need to) store values that exceed 32K, **use a `Long`**.

Comment: Thank you for your input, because when the time I design the system, I was careless and declare my variable all in integer type, after few years, the database transactions row has increased more than 32K, So I have to fix the bugs and change almost every variable to long type in my system.

Comment: So if I continue to develop in VB6, that means I should not using integer type for variable that fetch records from database transaction rows or auto increment primary key. Am I getting the point?

Comment: Depends - for example, if the max of your ID's will never be over 32K (like in a lookup table of country codes, etc.) then it's ok - but for IDs that will grow over time then I'd just go for the long.

Comment: Thank you. Is it only VB6 will facing this issues?
VB.NET will not having this problems?
It will auto convert to long if the data is too large?

Comment: Just VB6 - the equivelant in .Net would be a short - the int in .Net is substantially larger (Here's a quick link to the data types in .net)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7(VS.80).aspx